# Reference for equivariant Riemann-Roch formula?

Tags: reference-request, ag.algebraic-geometry, cohomology, equivariant

Is there any reference for equivariant Riemann-Roch formula: book, paper, notes or something? I want to compute the weight of the action of C^* on the top wedge of cohomology group.

Comment: Take a look at this paper http://www.ams.org/journals/jams/1996-9-02/S0894-0347-96-00197-X/S0894-0347-96-00197-X.pdf

Comment: Are you trying to understand why the Donaldson-Futaki invariant equals the classical Futaki invariant?

Comment: yeah,I am trying to use it to compute Donaldson-Futaki invariant of some examples such as Mukai-Tian type 3-fold in Arezzo & Vedova's paper. 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You also have some lecture notes on the web page of Michel Brion [here](http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~mbrion/notes.html).

This [paper](http://www.math.jussieu.fr/~vergne/publications2/Remplacer/83zerosdunchampdevecteurs.pdf) of N. Berline and M. Vergne is well written (but is more "Lie Group theoretic" than the previous references and it is written in french...).

Comment: The link to `math.jussieu.fr` is broken, but a snapshot is saved on the [Wayback Machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20120124154840/http://www.math.jussieu.fr/~vergne/publications2/Remplacer/83zerosdunchampdevecteurs.pdf). The article can also be found at [doi:10.1215/S0012-7094-83-05024-X](https://doi.org/10.1215/S0012-7094-83-05024-X) ([Zbl 0515.58007](https://zbmath.org/0515.58007)).

Answer (score 7):

You could try one or all of these (same authors):

- *Edidin, Dan; Graham, William*, [**Algebraic cycles and completions of equivariant $K$-theory**](https://doi.org/10.1215/00127094-2008-042), Duke Math. J. 144, No. 3, 489-524 (2008). [Zbl 1148.14007](https://zbmath.org/1148.14007).
- *Edidin, Dan; Graham, William*, [**Riemann-Roch for equivariant Chow groups**](https://doi.org/10.1215/S0012-7094-00-10239-6), Duke Math. J. 102, No. 3, 567-594 (2000). [Zbl 0997.14002](https://zbmath.org/0997.14002).
- *Edidin, Dan; Graham, William*, [**Equivariant intersection theory**](https://doi.org/10.1007/s002220050214), Invent. Math. 131, No. 3, 595-644 (1998). [Zbl 0940.14003](https://zbmath.org/0940.14003).